# Sails.js: stream socket and send to controller

Tags: node.js, websocket, salesforce, sails.js

I'm writing a REST API in Sails.js and alongside the regular HTTP routes, I need the application to listen for notifications on a socket from Salesforce.

I have a controller with some logic but I don't know how to get it to subscribe to the socket on startup, so right now nothing is reaching it.

**Controller**:

```
pushTopicHandler: function(req, res) {
  if (!req.isSocket) {
    return res.badRequest();
  }

  var nforce = require('nforce');
  var org = nforce.createConnection({
      clientId: sails.config.client_id,
      clientSecret: sails.config.client_secret,
      redirectUri: sails.config.callback_url + '/oauth/_callback',
      mode: 'multi',
      environment: 'sandbox'
  });

  org.authenticate({ username: sails.config.sfUsername, password: sails.config.sfPassword }, function(err, oauth) {

      if(err) return res.serverError(err);

      var str = org.stream({ topic: sails.config.push_topic, oauth: oauth });

      str.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('Connected to pushtopic: ' + sails.config.push_topic);
      });

      str.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log('Error received from pushtopic: ' + error);
      });

      str.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Received the following from pushtopic ---');
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sails has a `bootstrap.js` file which lets you write anything you want to run *before* the server lifts.

I was able to subscribe to the push topic in a small function before the `cb()` in that file and it works, the server starts the REST API normally and it's still listening for events.